# Get ASP within .html files to render on IIS Windows XP

Tags: iis, asp-classic, windows-xp

I have IIS running under Windows XP.
I have .html files with classic ASP content in them.  How do I get the ASP within these .html files to render properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell IIS to treat .html as it does .asp.

In IIS Manager, select the application/site you want to modify (and this will impact every .html in that folder and subfolder, so be careful about scope), go to the "Home Directory"/"Virtual Directory" tab of the properties and select configuration.

Modify (or create) the mapping for `.html` to match that of `.asp`.